# Do yartzeit glasses need to be toveled for use as drinking glasses?

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping

Do glass containers for yahrtzet candles need to be toveled to use as drinking glasses after the candles have been totally consumed?

Comment: Were they even bought from a non-Jew? Often they are manufactured by Jews and bought by Jews.

Comment: Perhaps your are asking about somwhat which is not made for drinking, and occasionally you want use it to drink. For instance, a laboratory flask? Perhaps are you asking about switch definitively utilisation, e.g.  a metal box may begin a cup.

Comment: @kouty  This is the way that I read the question. When the candle is removed from the glass container, you now have a small drinking glass. Now that it is to be used as such, does it require tevillah just as any other glass cup.

Comment: @sabbahillel so, you understand that they will be entirelly and definitely glass cup.

Comment: Perhaps the question is that A shinuy Hashem, to make from this a cup, which is made by a Jew, make it exempt from tevilah as if it is manufactured by him.

Comment: @kouty In the 60's, - at least the 80's, in the U.S., yizkor / yahrtzeit candles came in large glasses. My grandparents and parents commonly rinsed the glass out after the candle was used up (of course, scooping out the wick, metal, and any leftover wax) and on Shabbat they poured tea from a fancy teapot into a "measly" yahrtzeit glass - a strange "contradiction". These lasted as drinking glasses at meals until the next yizkor "cycle" after which the old glasses went to the bathroom for soar throat gargles w/ hot water and salt. Today, Rokeach makes them in much smaller (4 oz juice) glasses.

Comment: @kouty I'm unfamiliar with the requirement of tevillah. But, I gather that the concern occurs based on the initial intention of the item. Most pots, pans and glasses were intended for food use. A glass yartzeit candle, if manufactured by a non-Jew was intended to be used as a candle, not as a drinking glass. Would that intent, alone, exempt it from tevillah?

Comment: @DanF Not necessarily. The fact that you are now going to use it for food, would cause it to require tevilah. This would be similar to buying scissors to use to cut the chicken into parts.